# In MATLAB, How Do I Substitute Initial Value for Derivative in Laplace Transform?

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I have a .m script for working with inhomogeneous first-order linear IVP with constant coefficients in MATLAB; I'll use $\dot{x} - 3x = t^2$, $x(0) = 4$ as an example:

```
syms x(t) s X
Dx = diff(x(t),t)
ode = Dx - 3*x - t^2
x0 = 4

ODE = laplace(ode,t,s) % The t and s in laplace aren't necessary, as they are default
IVP = subs(ODE,{x(0)},{x0})
IVP = subs(IVP,{laplace(x(t),t,s)},{X})
IVP = collect(IVP,X)

X = solve(IVP, X)
X = partfrac(X)

sol = ilaplace(X, s, t)

Dsol = diff(sol,t)
check1 = Dsol - 3*sol
check2 = vpa(subs(sol, t, 0))
```

That works fine.

When I try to do a variation on this script for a second-order linear IVP with constant coefficients, I get stumped trying to substitute in for the value of the first derivative at t = 0 (using $\ddot{x} - 2\dot{x} - 3x = t^2$, $x(0) = 4$, $\dot{x} = 5$ as an example):

```
syms x(t) s X
Dx = diff(x,t)
D2x = diff(x, t, 2)
ode = D2x - 2*Dx - 3*x - t^2
x0 = 4
xdot0 = 5

ODE = laplace(ode,t,s)
IVP = subs(ODE,{x(0)},{x0})
IVP = subs(ODE,{D(x)(0)},{xdot0}) % <- <- THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE!!
IVP = subs(IVP,{laplace(x(t),t,s)},{X})
IVP = collect(IVP,X)

X = solve(IVP, X)
X = partfrac(X)

sol = ilaplace(X, s, t)

Dsol = diff(sol,t)
D2sol = diff(sol, t, 2)
check1 = D2sol - 2*Dsol - 3*sol
check2 = vpa(subs(sol, t, 0))
check3 = vpa(subs(Dsol, t, 0))
```

I'm not sure what to put as the variable D(x)(0) in the Laplace transform of the second derivative; everything I've tried gives me some kind of error or another. I had to resort to the kludgy

```
syms x(t) s X

a1 =-2
a0 = -3
x0 = 4
xdot0 = 5
rhs = t^2

Dx = diff(x,t)
D2x = diff(x,t,2)
lhs = D2x + a1*Dx + a0*x
ode = lhs - rhs

Lx = X 
LDx = s*X - x0
LD2x = s^2*X - x0*s - xdot0
LHS = LD2x + a1*LDx + a0*Lx
RHS = laplace(rhs,t,s)
IVP = LHS - RHS

IVP = collect(IVP,X)

X = solve(IVP, X)
X = partfrac(X)

sol = ilaplace(X, s, t)

Dsol = diff(sol,t)
D2sol = diff(sol,t,2)
check1 = D2sol + a1*Dsol + a0*sol
check2 = vpa(subs(sol, t, 0))
check3 = vpa(subs(Dsol, t, 0))
```

using a suggestion from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2160177/laplace-transform-of-differential-equations-using-matlab). All I really need to know is what to put in for "D(x)(0)". I tried 'D(x)(0)', diff(x,t)(0), Dx(0),

```
help = D(x)
IVP = subs(ODE,{help(0)},{xdot0})

help2 = diff(x,t)
IVP = subs(ODE,{help2(0)},{xdot0})
```

you name it, nothing worked.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.